# joomla: use API inside an article

Tags: api, frameworks, joomla, joomla1.5

I am using the [Sourcerer plugin](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/use-javascript-or-php-in-a-joomla-article/) to use PHP code inside my articles. I would like to use the Joomla API/framework inside my article to dynamically set the HTML meta tags and other stuff. [I found](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML%3a%3asetHeadData/1.5) the `setHeadData` method that should allow me do that but I have simply no idea as to how calling it.

**[Q] Can someone give me 1 example or point me to a tutorial that would help me get started on using that joomla API/framework please?**

**Answer**

Based on the numerous feedbacks all pointing in the same direction, using a content plugin to modify the head data is properly better than doing this via an article. If like me you want to do this in an article here is what I did:

(1) I used the snippet provided by ezpresso to set the head data inside my article.
(2) I modified the **libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php** file to change the way the head data was set there.

For instance you can set the title meta tag at step (1) and then at step (2) replace the following line:

```
$strHtml .= $tab.'<title>'.htmlspecialchars($document->getTitle()).'</title>'.$lnEnd;
```

with this one:

```
$strHtml .= $tab.'<title>'.htmlspecialchars($document['metaTags']['standard']['title']).'</title>'.$lnEnd;
```

You might also want to look into **libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php** to do some more cleanup in the head, like getting rid of the `generator` meta tag that Joomla inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source code of the method you are referring to:

```
/**
 * Set the html document head data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array   $data   The document head data in array form
 */
function setHeadData($data)
{
    $this->title        = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : $this->title;
    $this->description  = (isset($data['description'])) ? $data['description'] : $this->description;
    $this->link         = (isset($data['link'])) ? $data['link'] : $this->link;
    $this->_metaTags    = (isset($data['metaTags'])) ? $data['metaTags'] : $this->_metaTags;
    $this->_links       = (isset($data['links'])) ? $data['links'] : $this->_links;
    $this->_styleSheets = (isset($data['styleSheets'])) ? $data['styleSheets'] : $this->_styleSheets;
    $this->_style       = (isset($data['style'])) ? $data['style'] : $this->_style;
    $this->_scripts     = (isset($data['scripts'])) ? $data['scripts'] : $this->_scripts;
    $this->_script      = (isset($data['script'])) ? $data['script'] : $this->_script;
    $this->_custom      = (isset($data['custom'])) ? $data['custom'] : $this->_custom;
}
```

It is implemented in a JDocumentHtml class, which is located in a `libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php` directory.

Below is the links to some of the examples of how to use it:

- [setHeadData difference between j1.5 and j1.6](http://groups.google.com/group/joomlabugsquad/browse_thread/thread/ce970a6d3a9472cd)
- [Remove Mootools From Joomla Header](http://www.blog.highub.com/cms/joomla-cms/remove-mootools-from-joomla-header/)

I guess you may call the `setHeadData` method like this:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$options = $doc->getHeadData();
$options['metaTags'] = array("tag1", "tag2", "tag3"); // you may change the meta tags here
$doc->setHeadData($options);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I insert your code snippet it breaks joomla (I get a white page). I tried to get some debug information by declaring `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` before but I don't get anything. **Is there anything else I need to add before? (do I need to instantiate JFactory?)**

Comment: Actually I do get the PHP error output via apache error.log. Here is what I'm getting: `Call to undefined method plgSystemSourcererHelper::getHeadData()`

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your snippet (forgot the ; after `getHeadData()`). I was able to add the description html meta tag, however the problem is that joomla also inserts its own. I can't unset joomla's because it is set after I call `setHeadData`. Any idea as to how I can lock up the head data so that joomla can't add its own stuff after me?

Comment: I corrected the typo. I think it is not possible to lock up the head data, but there can be other solutions anyway. You may implement a system plug-in or a hook which can be triggered just before the page sent to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Putting PHP in the article is not a very good way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Joomla frameworks has an order of operation that determines when various functions and plugins run. Due to the order of operation, there are numerous functions that will happen after an article is rendered, probably negating any changes you make from within the article. You would be better off either using an extension to handle titles and meta tags rather than trying to do it inside the article.

Comment: Exactly - if it is easier for the OP to write this from scratch than find, I would recommend to write a Content plugin. Use any of the existing ones as an example